# Table styling in chrome - used to work but now doesn't

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, safari

I don't know if this is down to a chrome update or anything, but my table used to work in chrome just fine and now it looks like this:

[ajax table in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2GyK.jpg)

Oddly, here's the table working in Safari:

[ajax table in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0vz4.jpg)

Has anyone else experienced this? Here's the css for the table:

```
<style>

/*The CSS you need to achieve cellspacing="0" is

table {border-collapse: collapse;} */

table  {
width: 80%; 
height:100px;
border-collapse: collapse;
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

tr {
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 20px;
/*border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 3px;*/
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-right: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0,      0.19);

}

td {
float:left;
display: block;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

td:hover {
opacity: 0.9;
}

th {
display: block;
margin: 8px;
padding: 0;
text-align:center !important; 
color: #000;
font-family:'Dense-Regular';
font-size: 23px;
letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

table a:link {
color:black;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;
}

table a:hover {
color:white;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
background-color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.clickable-area {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ffefef;
}

.clickable-area:focus {
   outline: 0;
}


</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="pageHeader">

  <h1>Recommended events &amp; content in</h1>
  </div> <!-- Single button -->
<!-- where button event goes -->

<div class="form-group" id="locationdrop">
<form>
<select name="users" id ="location" onchange="showLocation(this.value)">
  <div id="locationphp"><option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Location'];?>" selected="selected"><?php
echo $_SESSION['Location'];?></option>  }
</div>
  <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>
  <option value="Nottingham">Nottingham</option>
  <option value="Leeds">Leeds</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
  </select>
</form>

<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Select a city.</b></div>
</div>
```

ajax:

```
<script>
function showLocation(str) {

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("locationphp").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getLocation.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

php:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table>"; 
    echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<td>"?> <img src= "<?php echo $row ['event-photo']; ?>" height="300" width="300"> <?php echo "</td> ";
    echo "<th>" . $row['name'] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row['date'] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row['overview'] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row['Location'] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row['venue'] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>"?> <a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>" target="_blank" >Get tickets</a> <?php echo "</th>";
    //if discount = yes then display the logo with a hover and pop up like... will need to import j query
    //echo  "<th>" <div class ="mellado_offer" data-role="popup" id="popupArrow" data-arrow="true">
    //<p>A paragraph inside the popup with an arrow.</p>
    //<p>This second paragraph serves to increase the height of the popup</p>
    //</div><a href="#" id="open-popupArrow" class="clickable-area"></a> "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance to any replies :)

Comment: Would you be able to post sufficient HTML and CSS to reproduce the issue? It'd certainly help other users be able to more quickly track down where the problem lies.

Comment: @Serlite that's been edited, cheers

Comment: I totally don't understand why you use tables for this. Moreover, if you want to have image and then text, why don't you create 2 rows in table ?

Comment: @moped not sure what you mean, could you expand please?

Comment: tables are hardly used for design purpose, they are meant to hold data. but if you're not able to do it with proper html elements, at least put image in one `<tr></tr>` and `<th>` in another `<tr></tr>`